# Can too much logging impact the performance of web application?

Tags: python, django, performance, logging, web

For a web application written in python/Django, does logging volumn impact web performance?

For Go, I can start a goroutine to write logs asynchronously, but AFAIK, python logging is synchronous, log writing is part of request processing. But how much time does it take generally, compared to other activities like accessing DB, or rendering template, etc? Should I be concerned?

I am not using any specific logging handlers, just writeing to plain log files.

I understand I can adjust logging levels to reduce the amount of logs produced, but I still want to keep as much logs as possible if it doesn't seriously impact performance.

Comment: It heavily depends on the taken strategy, amount of logs, disk performance and the traffic ending up in your app. You have variety of log handlers available and their performance differs. You can write to a `local file`, use `logstash` or even `redis` to log into. It's also possible to write a custom handler. But the question is __too broad__ without any details given so I guess it will be closed soon if it stays in the current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about I/O latency (a valid concern), you could log from the web application to a queue using `QueueHandler` / `QueueListener` as described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block). The `QueueListener` can operate on a separate thread and prevent your request handler threads from getting bogged down in logging I/O. If you are using Python 2.x, then `QueueHandler` / `QueueListener` are available in the [logutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) package on PyPI.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should log all the data that can be usefull for any future analysis. But you should concern about logging overhead if you are logging too much of data in sync. There can be many options for async logging.

- We are using [redis](http://redis.io/) server pubsub model for this ( for example [visit this link](https://gist.github.com/jobliz/2596594) ).
- The other option could be using [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery).